# Did not Pop appears in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, xml, json

Hereby i have design this activity, My data from webservice is properly working, but i can't get the dropdownlist. here i convert the arraylist into String array for show the result in autocomplete.Kindly help me. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

**File:proprety.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menubar12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/property_header"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            android:onClick="myclick_home" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menubar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logout"
                android:onClick="myclick_logout" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/et_propertyact_propertyname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/property_text"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Property Name"
                 android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                 android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

                <requestFocus />
            </AutoCompleteTextView>

              <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/et_propertyact_blockname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/block_text"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Block Name"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                 android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </AutoCompleteTextView>

             <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/et_propertyact_appartmentname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/apartment"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Apartment Name"
                 android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                 android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </AutoCompleteTextView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bg_buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_propertyact_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/view_button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/property_listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/cellborder" android:dividerHeight="1dp"         android:focusable="true" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**File:PropertyActivity.Java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.webservice.JSONfunction_JSONArray;
import com.example.webservice.JSONfunction_JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class PropertyActivity extends Activity {
    /* ====Components Declaration Part Begins here======= */
    private ListView property_listView;

    private ListView list_property;
    private Button btn_view;
    private AutoCompleteTextView propertyname, blockname, apartmentname;
    private static final String TAG = "AppSquare";

    /* ====ServiceVariables Declarations Part ======= */
    JSONArray j_array,j_array1;
    JSONObject j_obj,j_obj1;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrList_proprty_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrList_property_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrList_block_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrList_apartment_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrList_property_names_id= new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrList_block_names_id= new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrList_apartment_names_id= new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> PropAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> BlockAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> ApartmentAdapter;
    public static String[] arr_Prop_name;
    public static String[] arr_block_name;
    public static String[] arr_apartment_name;




    /* ====API Declarations Part ======= */
    public static final String ip = "192.168.0.6";
    String API_propSelect = "http://" + ip + "/APP2/propertySelect.php";
    String API_blockSelect = "http://" + ip + "/APP2/blockSelect.php";
    String API_apartmentSelect = "http://" + ip + "/APP2/apartmentSelect.php";
    String API_propDetails = "http://" + ip + "/App2/propertyDetails.php";


    /* ====OnClick Declarations Part ======= */
    /* ====OnClick Definition Part Begins here======= */
    public void myclick_logout(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                PropertyActivity.this);
        builder2.setTitle("Warning");
        builder2.setMessage("Closing Application..");
        builder2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // finish();
                // System.exit(0);
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
                finish();

            }

        });

        builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                });

        builder2.show();
    }

    public void myclick_home(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(PropertyActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class));

    }

    /* ====OnCreate Definition Part Begins here======= */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.property_activity);
        getPrefernces();
        new PropName().execute();
        new BlockName().execute();
        new ApartmentName().execute();
        setValue_AutoComplete();
        Viewbtn_action();   



    }

    public void getPrefernces()
    {
            property_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.property_listView);
            propertyname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_propertyact_propertyname);
            blockname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_propertyact_blockname);
            apartmentname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_propertyact_appartmentname);
            btn_view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_propertyact_view);
    }
    public void setValue_AutoComplete()
    {
        /*-------Load Data into PropertList-----*/
        arr_Prop_name = arrList_property_names.toArray(new String[arrList_property_names.size()]);
        PropAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PropertyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr_Prop_name);
        propertyname.setAdapter(PropAdapter);
        propertyname.getDropDownBackground().setAlpha(255);
        propertyname.setThreshold(1);

    /*------Load Data into Block List------*/
        arr_block_name = arrList_block_names.toArray(new String[arrList_block_names.size()]);
        BlockAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PropertyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr_block_name);
        blockname.setAdapter(BlockAdapter);
        blockname.getDropDownBackground().setAlpha(255);
        blockname.setThreshold(1);
    /*------Load Data into apartment List------*/
        arr_apartment_name = arrList_apartment_names.toArray(new String[arrList_apartment_names.size()]);
        ApartmentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PropertyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr_apartment_name);
        apartmentname.setAdapter(ApartmentAdapter);
        apartmentname.getDropDownBackground().setAlpha(255);
        apartmentname.setThreshold(1);
    }



    private void Viewbtn_action() {
        btn_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

    }


        class PropName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
        {       


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    System.out.println("In Background...PropName");
                    System.out.println(API_propSelect);                 
                    j_obj=JSONfunction_JSONObject.getJSONfromURL(API_propSelect);
                    Log.d(TAG, "JSON_RES" + j_obj);
                    j_array = j_obj.getJSONArray("property");
                    for (int i = 0; i < j_array.length(); i++)
                    {
                        j_obj1 = j_array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id= j_obj1.getString("Id");
                        String value=j_obj1.getString("Value");
                        System.out.println("Id------>"+id);
                        System.out.println("Value------>"+value);
                        //arrList_property_names_id.add(id);
                        arrList_property_names.add(value);
                        //System.out.println("Value in array list------>"+arrList_property_names_id);
                        System.out.println("Value in array list------>"+arrList_property_names);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Error", "Error in API" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                    }

                return "";
            }

        }


    class BlockName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                System.out.println("In Background...BlockName");
                System.out.println(API_blockSelect);

                j_obj=JSONfunction_JSONObject.getJSONfromURL(API_blockSelect);
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON_RES" + j_obj);
                j_array = j_obj.getJSONArray("apartment");

                for (int i = 0; i < j_array.length(); i++)
                {
                    j_obj1 = j_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id= j_obj1.getString("Id");
                    String value=j_obj1.getString("Value");
                    System.out.println("Id------>"+id);
                    System.out.println("Value------>"+value);
                    //arrList_block_names_id.add(id);
                    arrList_block_names.add(value);
                    //System.out.println("Value in array list------>"+arrList_block_names_id);
                    System.out.println("Value in array list------>"+arrList_block_names);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", "Error in API" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }

            return "";

        }

    }
    class ApartmentName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                System.out.println("In Background...ApartmentName");
                System.out.println(API_apartmentSelect);

                j_obj=JSONfunction_JSONObject.getJSONfromURL(API_apartmentSelect);
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON_RES" + j_obj);
                j_array = j_obj.getJSONArray("block");

                for (int i = 0; i < j_array.length(); i++)
                {
                    j_obj1 = j_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id= j_obj1.getString("Id");
                    String value=j_obj1.getString("Value");
                    System.out.println("Id------>"+id);
                    System.out.println("Value------>"+value);
                    //arrList_apartment_names_id.add(id);
                    arrList_apartment_names.add(value);
                    //System.out.println("Value in array list------>"+arrList_apartment_names_id);
                    System.out.println("Value in array list------>"+arrList_apartment_names);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", "Error in API" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }

            return "";
        }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got answer 
1.Implements Texwatcher
2.override the OnTextChanged();
Thats it...

```
public class PropertyActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    propertyname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_propertyact_propertyname);
                propertyname.addTextChangedListener(this);
                blockname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_propertyact_blockname);
                blockname.addTextChangedListener(this);
                apartmentname = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_propertyact_appartmentname);
                apartmentname.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

        @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PropAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PropertyActivity.this,R.layout.my_autolist_item,arr_Prop_name);
            //  propertyname.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
                propertyname.getDropDownBackground().setAlpha(255);
                propertyname.setThreshold(1);
                propertyname.setAdapter(PropAdapter);

                BlockAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PropertyActivity.this,R.layout.my_autolist_item,arr_block_name);
             // blockname.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
                blockname.getDropDownBackground().setAlpha(255);
                blockname.setThreshold(1);
                blockname.setAdapter(BlockAdapter);

                ApartmentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PropertyActivity.this,R.layout.my_autolist_item,arr_apartment_name);
             // apartmentname.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
                apartmentname.getDropDownBackground().setAlpha(255);
                apartmentname.setThreshold(1);
                apartmentname.setAdapter(ApartmentAdapter);
            }
    }
```